# GRUB: Reboot PC after typing wrong password to decrypt OS partition

Tags: grub2, luks

I have encrypted with LUKS the OS and swap partition on my laptop. When I boot if I type the wrong password it stops at the first attempt. This seems strange, but it's all right for me. The trouble is that it immediately enters in grub rescue mode and most of the grub commands I can see in the manual don't work. I assume that no extra module is loaded while in rescue mode. I just would like to reboot my PC, but **halt**, **normal**, or similar commands are not recognised. The only way is to shutdown with the hardware button. Is there a nicer way to reboot?

The OS is OpenSUSE 15.2
GRUB2 2.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's "normal" (debatable whether it's a GRUB bug or a feature) if GRUB asks for the LUKS password before showing the boot menu.
I just press Ctrl+Alt+Del to reboot in such a case.

Comment: Thank you, I tried to type all the possible commands, but I didn't think about pressing Ctrl+Alt+Del